# Laravel Sanctum authenticate middleware auth:sanctum for different model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm using Laravel Sanctum 3.x in my Laravel 9 project. I'm building a Microservice feature and need to authenticate them via my `Microservice` model where I've added `HasApiTokens` and created my tokens.

I've created the extra auth config:

```php
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'microservice' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'microservices',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
    'microservices' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\Microservice::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

Then, inside my controller where I'd like to use my microservice auth check rather than the default `auth:sanctum` middleware check I'm confused as to what to add?

This is my controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Hub;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Responses\ApiSuccessResponse;
use App\Http\Responses\ApiErrorResponse;
use App\Http\Responses\ApiValidationErrorResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Microservice;

class HubController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Instantiate a new HubController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        // TODO: how to change to Microservice auth?
        $this->middleware('auth:sanctum');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
            'message' => 'Hub controller - post'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Would I just need to change the `auth:sanctum` to `auth:microservice` and then it would validate the token?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass guard to your authentication logic .

```
if(auth()->guard('microservices')->attempt($request->only('email','password'))) {
    return auth()->guard('admin')->user(); }
```